# Android and how to change a string object to json object

Tags: android, json, rest

I am trying to get a response from my server using restful services, I get it back in json format, change to a string variable then am trying to change from a string variable to json object, but I am getting an error here is my class and after my class is my stacktrace and then my string variable, the error occurs when i try to convert from string to json object, thanks for your help:

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String response = "";
            for (String url : urls) {
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                try {
                    HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                    InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(content));
                    String s = "";
                    while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                        response += s;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            try {
                //JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONObject data = new JSONObject(response).getJSONObject("type");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return response;
        }
```

> 11-14 09:53:26.192: W/System.err(560): org.json.JSONException: Value
>   [{"type":"HumVideoMovingImage","location":"http://hummedia.byu.edu/watch/humvideo:0373889/","label":"Harry
>   Potter und der Orden des
>   Phonix","videoinfo":{"id":"humvideo:0373889","title":"Harry Potter und
>   der Orden des
>   Phonix","height":480,"coverage":"BYU","status":"allowed","subject":"Harry
>   Potter,magic","description":"Lord Voldemort ist zuruckgekehrt, doch
>   das Zaubereiministerium tut alles, um diese Tatsache der Geme
>   ...","width":716,"rights":"shared","language":["de"],"runningtime":7200,"date":"2007-04-11"}},{"type":"HumVideoMovingImage","location":"http://hummedia.byu.edu/watch/humvideo:0330373/","label":"Harry
>   Potter und der
>   Feuerkelch","videoinfo":{"id":"humvideo:0330373","title":"Harry Potter
>   und der
>   Feuerkelch","height":480,"coverage":"BYU","status":"allowed","subject":"Harry
>   Potter,magic","description":"Das grosse Abenteuer beginnt, als der
>   Feuerkelch Harry Potters Namen freigibt und Harry damit Teilne
>   ...","width":716,"rights":"shared","language":["de"],"runningtime":7200,"date":"2005-11-18"}},{"type":"HumVideoMovingImage","location":"http://hummedia.byu.edu/watch/humvideo:0304141/","label":"Harry
>   Potter und der Gefangene von
>   Askaban","videoinfo":{"id":"humvideo:0304141","title":"Harry Potter
>   und der Gefangene von
>   Askaban","height":480,"coverage":"BYU","status":"allowed","subject":"Harry
>   Potter,magic","description":"Wahrend die abscheuliche Tante Magda uber
>   den Nachthimmel schwebt, kehrt Harry nach Hogwarts zuruck,
>   ...","width":716,"rights":"shared","language":["de"],"runningtime":7200,"date":"2003-06-04"}},{"type":"HumVideoMovingImage","location":"http://hummedia.byu.edu/watch/humvideo:0295297/","label":"Harry
>   Potter und die Kammer
>   Desschreckens","videoinfo":{"id":"humvideo:0295297","title":"Harry
>   Potter und die Kammer
>   Desschreckens","height":480,"coverage":"BYU","status":"allowed","subject":"Harry
>   Potter,magic","description":"Fliegende Autos, gemeingefahrliche Baume
>   und die Warnung eines mysteriosen Hauselfen - so beginnt fu
>   ...","width":716,"rights":"shared","language":["de"],"runningtime":7200,"date":"2002-11-15"}},{"type":"HumVideoMovingImage","location":"http://hummedia.byu.edu/watch/humvideo:0241527/","label":"Harry
>   Potter und der Stein der
>   Weisen","videoinfo":{"id":"humvideo:0241527","title":"Harry Potter und
>   der Stein der
>   Weisen","height":480,"coverage":"BYU","status":"allowed","subject":"Harry
>   Potter,magic","description":"In der zauberhaften Verfilmung J.K.
>   Rowlings Weltbestseller erfahrt Harry Potter an seinem 11. Gebur
>   ...","width":716,"rights":"shared","language":["de"],"runningtime":7200,"date":"2001-11-16"}}]
>   of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject 11-14
>   09:53:26.232: W/System.err(560):  at
>   org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111) 11-14 09:53:26.242:
>   W/System.err(560):    at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:158)
>   11-14 09:53:26.252: W/System.err(560):    at
>   org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:171) 11-14 09:53:26.262:
>   W/System.err(560):    at
>   de.vogella.android.asynctask.ReadWebpageAsyncTask$DownloadWebPageTask.doInBackground(ReadWebpageAsyncTask.java:56)
>   11-14 09:53:26.332: W/System.err(560):    at
>   de.vogella.android.asynctask.ReadWebpageAsyncTask$DownloadWebPageTask.doInBackground(ReadWebpageAsyncTask.java:1)
>   11-14 09:53:26.352: W/System.err(560):    at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264) 11-14 09:53:26.372:
>   W/System.err(560):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>   11-14 09:53:26.382: W/System.err(560):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 11-14
>   09:53:26.392: W/System.err(560):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208) 11-14
>   09:53:26.402: W/System.err(560):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>   11-14 09:53:26.412: W/System.err(560):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>   11-14 09:53:26.422: W/System.err(560):    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 11-14 09:53:34.635:
>   D/dalvikvm(169): GC_CONCURRENT freed 396K, 7% free 7350K/7879K, paused
>   21ms+9ms

string variable:

> [            {            "type": "HumVideoMovingImage",
>   "videoinfo": {                "status": "allowed",
>     "description": "Lord Voldemort ist zuruckgekehrt, doch das
>   Zaubereiministerium tut alles, um diese Tatsache der Geme ...",
>     "height": 480,              "coverage": "BYU",              "date":
>   "2007-04-11",             "id": "humvideo:0373889",
>     "subject": "Harry Potter,magic",                "language": ["de"],
>     "rights": "shared",             "title": "Harry Potter und der Orden
>   des Phonix",              "runningtime": 7200,                "width": 716
>   },            "location":
>   "http://hummedia.byu.edu/watch/humvideo:0373889/",            "label":
>   "Harry Potter und der Orden des Phonix"            },            {
>   "type": "HumVideoMovingImage",            "videoinfo": {
>     "status": "allowed",                "description": "Das grosse Abenteuer
>   beginnt, als der Feuerkelch Harry Potters Namen freigibt und Harry
>   damit Teilne ...",                "height": 480,              "coverage":
>   "BYU",                "date": "2005-11-18",               "id":
>   "humvideo:0330373",               "subject": "Harry Potter,magic",
>     "language": ["de"],             "rights": "shared",
>     "title": "Harry Potter und der Feuerkelch",
>     "runningtime": 7200,                "width": 716            },
>   "location": "http://hummedia.byu.edu/watch/humvideo:0330373/",
>   "label": "Harry Potter und der Feuerkelch"            },            { 
>   "type": "HumVideoMovingImage",            "videoinfo": {
>     "status": "allowed",                "description": "Wahrend die
>   abscheuliche Tante Magda uber den Nachthimmel schwebt, kehrt Harry
>   nach Hogwarts zuruck, ...",               "height": 480,
>     "coverage": "BYU",              "date": "2003-06-04",
>     "id": "humvideo:0304141",               "subject": "Harry
>   Potter,magic",                "language": ["de"],             "rights":
>   "shared",             "title": "Harry Potter und der Gefangene von
>   Askaban",             "runningtime": 7200,                "width": 716
>   },            "location":
>   "http://hummedia.byu.edu/watch/humvideo:0304141/",            "label":
>   "Harry Potter und der Gefangene von Askaban"            },
>   {            "type": "HumVideoMovingImage",            "videoinfo": { 
>     "status": "allowed",                "description": "Fliegende Autos,
>   gemeingefahrliche Baume und die Warnung eines mysteriosen Hauselfen -
>   so beginnt fu ...",               "height": 480,              "coverage":
>   "BYU",                "date": "2002-11-15",               "id":
>   "humvideo:0295297",               "subject": "Harry Potter,magic",
>     "language": ["de"],             "rights": "shared",
>     "title": "Harry Potter und die Kammer Desschreckens",
>     "runningtime": 7200,                "width": 716            },
>   "location": "http://hummedia.byu.edu/watch/humvideo:0295297/",
>   "label": "Harry Potter und die Kammer Desschreckens"            },
>   {            "type": "HumVideoMovingImage",            "videoinfo": { 
>     "status": "allowed",                "description": "In der zauberhaften
>   Verfilmung J.K. Rowlings Weltbestseller erfahrt Harry Potter an seinem
>   11. Gebur ...",               "height": 480,              "coverage": "BYU",              "date": "2001-11-16",               "id":
>   "humvideo:0241527",               "subject": "Harry Potter,magic",
>     "language": ["de"],             "rights": "shared",
>     "title": "Harry Potter und der Stein der Weisen",
>     "runningtime": 7200,                "width": 716            },
>   "location": "http://hummedia.byu.edu/watch/humvideo:0241527/",
>   "label": "Harry Potter und der Stein der Weisen"            }
>
> ```
>     ]
> ```

by trying to use the following code:
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);

I still get an error, here is the stack trace:

11-14 10:03:02.713: W/System.err(622): org.json.JSONException: Value [{"type":"HumVideoMovingImage","location":"http://hummedia.byu.edu/watch/humvideo:0373889/","label":"Harry Potter und der Orden des Phonix","videoinfo":{"id":"humvideo:0373889","title":"Harry Potter und der Orden des Phonix","height":480,"coverage":"BYU","status":"allowed","subject":"Harry Potter,magic","description":"Lord Voldemort ist zuruckgekehrt, doch das Zaubereiministerium tut alles, um diese Tatsache der Geme ...","width":716,"rights":"shared","language":["de"],"runningtime":7200,"date":"2007-04-11"}},{"type":"HumVideoMovingImage","location":"http://hummedia.byu.edu/watch/humvideo:0330373/","label":"Harry Potter und der Feuerkelch","videoinfo":{"id":"humvideo:0330373","title":"Harry Potter und der Feuerkelch","height":480,"coverage":"BYU","status":"allowed","subject":"Harry Potter,magic","description":"Das grosse Abenteuer beginnt, als der Feuerkelch Harry Potters Namen freigibt und Harry damit Teilne ...","width":716,"rights":"shared","language":["de"],"runningtime":7200,"date":"2005-11-18"}},{"type":"HumVideoMovingImage","location":"http://hummedia.byu.edu/watch/humvideo:0304141/","label":"Harry Potter und der Gefangene von Askaban","videoinfo":{"id":"humvideo:0304141","title":"Harry Potter und der Gefangene von Askaban","height":480,"coverage":"BYU","status":"allowed","subject":"Harry Potter,magic","description":"Wahrend die abscheuliche Tante Magda uber den Nachthimmel schwebt, kehrt Harry nach Hogwarts zuruck, ...","width":716,"rights":"shared","language":["de"],"runningtime":7200,"date":"2003-06-04"}},{"type":"HumVideoMovingImage","location":"http://hummedia.byu.edu/watch/humvideo:0295297/","label":"Harry Potter und die Kammer Desschreckens","videoinfo":{"id":"humvideo:0295297","title":"Harry Potter und die Kammer Desschreckens","height":480,"coverage":"BYU","status":"allowed","subject":"Harry Potter,magic","description":"Fliegende Autos, gemeingefahrliche Baume und die Warnung eines mysteriosen Hauselfen - so beginnt fu ...","width":716,"rights":"shared","language":["de"],"runningtime":7200,"date":"2002-11-15"}},{"type":"HumVideoMovingImage","location":"http://hummedia.byu.edu/watch/humvideo:0241527/","label":"Harry Potter und der Stein der Weisen","videoinfo":{"id":"humvideo:0241527","title":"Harry Potter und der Stein der Weisen","height":480,"coverage":"BYU","status":"allowed","subject":"Harry Potter,magic","description":"In der zauberhaften Verfilmung J.K. Rowlings Weltbestseller erfahrt Harry Potter an seinem 11. Gebur ...","width":716,"rights":"shared","language":["de"],"runningtime":7200,"date":"2001-11-16"}}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
11-14 10:03:02.732: W/System.err(622):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
11-14 10:03:02.752: W/System.err(622):  at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:158)
11-14 10:03:02.762: W/System.err(622):  at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:171)
11-14 10:03:02.822: W/System.err(622):  at de.vogella.android.asynctask.ReadWebpageAsyncTask$DownloadWebPageTask.doInBackground(ReadWebpageAsyncTask.java:56)
11-14 10:03:02.842: W/System.err(622):  at de.vogella.android.asynctask.ReadWebpageAsyncTask$DownloadWebPageTask.doInBackground(ReadWebpageAsyncTask.java:1)
11-14 10:03:02.852: W/System.err(622):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
11-14 10:03:02.872: W/System.err(622):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-14 10:03:02.892: W/System.err(622):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-14 10:03:02.902: W/System.err(622):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
11-14 10:03:02.912: W/System.err(622):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-14 10:03:02.922: W/System.err(622):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-14 10:03:02.942: W/System.err(622):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simple have to use below code

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
```

For rest you can process in the same way

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention I do have the import: "import org.json.JSONObject;
"

Comment: I tried the above solution but i still get an error, I have updated my question with new stack trace. thank you.

Comment: could you please try something like  
  
    JSONArray dataArray = new JSONArray(response);
    JSONObject menuObject = dataArray.getJSONObject(0);
                          menuObject.getString("type")

Answer (score 2):

The JSON returned from the server is an Array object, and the stack trace clearly states that.
Try using a org.json.JSONArray in place of an org.json.JSONObject:

```
org.json.JSONArray jsonArray = new org.json.JSONArray(response);
```

Comment: look in your stack trace for this line:
*type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject 11-14 10:03:02.732: W/System.err(622): at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)*